# In c#, Can I still use Windows.Forms.Timers in a new Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm trying to create a game where a cannon shoots projectiles. I want to keep lag down so I would like to make it so that each time a projectile is created, it is created in a new thread. To do this I have used the following code:

```
Image cubeImage= Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Stefan\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Game1\\Game1\\Resources\\CannonCube.png");
PictureBox cannonCube = new PictureBox();
ScreenPanel.Controls.Add(cannonCube);
cannonCube.Image = cubeImage;
cannonCube.SetBounds(cannonCubeInst.X, cannonCubeInst.Y, cubeImage.Width, cubeImage.Height);
cannonCube.BringToFront();
ParameterizedThreadStart pthread = new ParameterizedThreadStart(createShot);
Thread thread = new Thread(pthread);
thread.Start();
cps.Add(cannonCube);
```

The objects were created and worked fine before I tried to create them in a thread. Now, after using threads, they are created, but they do not move, so I suspect that the System.Windows.Forms.Timer objects I am using to time the movement have stopped operating.

Does this mean that I can't use the Timers in my theads?

I am not declaring the timers as static variables, I declare them inside the constructor:

```
public CubeProjectile(PictureBox box1, int u, int angle, List<PictureBox> walls)
{
System.Windows.Forms.Timer update;
System.Windows.Forms.Timer wallCheck;
wallList = walls;
u = u / 6;
horizontalSpeed = u * (Math.Cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180)));
verticalSpeed = u * (Math.Sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180)));
box = box1;
update = new Timer();
update.Interval = 29 - u/10;
update.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
update.Start();
wallCheck = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
wallCheck.Interval = 5;
wallCheck.Tick += new EventHandler(checkWall);
wallCheck.Start();
}
}
```

Comment: "I want to keep lag down so I would like to make it so that each time a projectile is created, it is created in a new thread." - how well do you think that will scale? You will run out of threads relatively quickly. Also creating (rather than using a pool thread) is relatively expensive.

Comment: You can run out of threads? Will it give me a StackOverflow error like when a method recursively calls itself too many times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot use that Timer in a thread.  It is not exactly like your program will implode because the class is fundamentally thread-unsafe, the timer just won't Tick because the worker thread you created isn't pumping a message loop like the UI thread does.

You are almost certainly solving the wrong problem, starting with your program not using the traditional game loop.  These statements are a strong indicator of trouble:

```
 update.Interval = 29 - u/10;
 //...
 wallCheck.Interval = 5;
```

Timers are not nearly that accurate.  They can only tick when a clock interrupt wakes up the processor from the halt state.  By default that happens 64 times per second on Windows.  Or in other words, only Interval values of 15.625, 31.250, 46.875, etcetera can be accurate.  You can't use floating point values so you use 15, 31, 46, etcetera.  So the real update rate of your game right now is much slower, that's easy to mis-interpret as a lag problem.

And you have no guarantee that the real interval is close to that so you must measure the actual elapsed time to calculate the new position.  A Stopwatch is fine for that, Environment.TickCount is okay as well, it has the same resolution as a timer.  The clock interrupt rate can be changed btw, a not infrequent hack in a game.  You'd pinvoke timeBeginPeriod().  Don't go there yet, a 15.625 msec interval is plenty good enough to keep the bullets flying realistically to a human eye.